# What does the orientation.flow represent in farnebacks method?

Tags: orientation

Which is the orientation/angle exactly? Between which vectors?

Is it the angle between the first frame and the second frame?

Answer (score 0):

Estimating Optical Flow delivers you a displacement matrix in pixels.
You get the displacement in the x direction and the displacement in y direction.

A person walking from bottom left to top right might give you a flow mean  of x=5 and y = -5. As you got a vector, you can calculate the angle using arctan(5/5) = 45 degrees